# number_in_month exercise (Error: syntax error: replacing COLON with AS)

Tags: sml

this is homework from the ProgLang course at Coursera but the due date has passed and I'm only auditing this. This is a really cheap problem but it looks like I can't do this in SML.

Given a list of date 3-tuples of int and an int, return how often that int matches #2 of the tuple (the month).

At first I had a lot of [tycon mismatch] and then played around with the function header. I have no idea how to denote a list of tuples, prolly all down to that.

```
fun number_in_month (date : [int*int*int], month : int) : int =
if hd date = []
then 0
else
if #2 hd date = month
then
    1 + number_in_month tl date
else
    0 + number_in_month tl date
```

Not sure about the logic and the if then else if construct either. And what on earth is AS ?

```
- use "hw1.sml";
[opening hw1.sml]
hw1.sml:13.26 Error: syntax error: replacing  COLON  with  AS
val it = () : unit
```

13:26 is the first colon of the header. Maybe I'm too numb to google too, I did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SML the list type is written as `elementType list`, not `[elementType]`. So the type of a list of int-triples is `(int*int*int) list`, not `[int*int*int]`.

So when SML sees the `[`, it thinks that it's seeing the start of a pattern (specifically a list pattern), not a type. That makes it think that the `:` is wrong (since a `:` must be followed by a type) and the error recovery algorithm replaces it with an `as` because that would be valid between an identifier and a pattern.

> And what on earth is AS ?

It's a keyword used in pattern matches to assign a name to the result of a pattern match. For example if you want to match a three-element list with a list pattern, but you also want a name for the entire list you can write `fun number_in_month (date as [x1, x2, x3]) = ...`. In this case, the three elements of the list would be known as `x1`, `x2` and `x3` respectively and the whole list would be known as `date`.

Now there's no reason that you'd want to use the `as` keyword here. It just happens to be what the parser comes up with because `fun number_in_month (date as [` can be the start of a syntactically valid program, but `fun number_in_month (date : [` can not be.

---

So your fixed signature should look like this:

```
number_in_month (date : (int*int*int) list, month : int) : int =
```

Now you'll get a bunch of type errors in the body of the function relating to some missing parentheses (for example`#2 hd date` is equivalent to the ill-typed `(#2 hd) date`, not `#2 (hd date)`, which is what you want) and the fact that `number_in_month` takes two arguments, not one (in other words: you're missing the `date` argument when calling `number_in_month` recursively).